# ruby calling one method from another method returns nil instead of a value

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby class which is shown in its entirety at the end of this question. It has 2 public instance methods. The 1st public instance method is named `plus` and the 2nd is named `multiply`.

When I call just `Adder.new(3, 4).plus` it returns `7` which is the expected value from adding `3` and `4`. However, in the `multiply` instance method, I first call the `plus` instance method and it constantly returns `nil` but if I call the `plus` instance method on its own it returns the correct value as shown below.

Why does `plus` instance method return `nil` when called from inside the `multiply` instance method?

Calling the `plus` instance method

```
Adder.new(3, 4).plus
# adding figures 
# I am the added value  7.0
```

calling the **multiply** instance method

```
Adder.new(3, 4).multiply 
# called from multiply value for plus is nil
```

The entire class is pasted below:

```
class Adder

  def self.plus( first, second)
    new(first, second).multiply
  end

  def initialize(first, second)
   @first = first
   @second = second
  end

  def plus
   puts 'adding figures'
   @k = add_them(@first, @second)
   puts "I am @k = #{@k}"
  end

  def multiply(third = 10)
   #@results = @k
   @result = plus
   #@result = add_them(@first, @second) 
   puts "called from multiply method value for plus is #{@results.inspect}"
 end

 private

 def add_them(first, second)
  @added = (first +  second).round(4)
  puts "I am the added value  #{@added}"
 end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts "I am @k = #{@k}"
```

The above returns `nil`  - [`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns `nil`. You can use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) to print the value you are returning:

```
def plus
  puts 'adding figures'
  (@k = add_them(@first, @second)).tap do
    puts "I am @k = #{@k}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Or just add `@k` as the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` does not return a value;

```
  def plus
   puts 'adding figures'
   @k = add_them(@first, @second)
   puts "I am @k = #{@k}"
  end
```

should be

```
  def plus
    add_them @first, @second
  end
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. All the answers were helpful, so I accepted one and upvoted the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Because the last method executed in `plus` is `puts`, which returns `nil`.